# How do I detect hijaiyah character in canvas Android?

Tags: android, ocr, arabic

I would like to know how to detect Arabic hijaiyah character in canvas Android when I draw?

Or are can anyone convert this project to Android 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvRrD4aFTu0

Comment: What you have you attempted?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see How to Ask and take the tour.